# cvt transmission

Tags: nissan, shifting, cvt-transmission, pathfinder

I have a 2015 nissan pathfinder. It seems to take a long time when you shift into reverse. Other than that it seems fine. Has anybody else had that problem. My dealer says that at some point it had the wrong fluid in it and that is what caused the problem. I had all the transmission oil flushed and changed at around 10,000 miles because the dealer said it had the wrong fluid in it.

Comment: So the factory put the wrong transmission fluid in? I'm pretty skeptical of that...

Answer (score 3):

My 2013 Subaru Impreza has a CVT as well. It also takes longer than a conventional automatic transmission to go into reverse. I was told that it's just the nature of CVTs.